# What is this thing on top of my bucket of resin?

Tags: epoxy-resin, tool-identification

I have a giant unopened bucket of HTR 386 resin, but I don't know what this plastic half-circle thing is on the top of the lid

[image: resin bucket lid]

It's surrounded by a solid metal circle, and the plastic half-circles lift up a little at the sides, but that seems to be all.

I've contacted the company, but no response yet.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The lid to the pouring spout :) I know them from cans of turpentine. Those two plastic semi-circles can be lifted to give a better grip when unscrewing the lid.

This picture gives a better ...picture:

[image]
<sup>[source](https://sc01.alicdn.com/kf/UTB8SR8utlahduJk43Jaq6zM8FXar/206319027/UTB8SR8utlahduJk43Jaq6zM8FXar.jpg)</sup>

Most images of versions of the rectangular tin cans that often feature them lead to dead links, so I've not been able to find a name for this kind of plugs yet.

Comment: Often you can pull up the lid (still closed) by those half circles.